# Working with Template Instances

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

My problem: I have multiple instances of the 'myTemp' template on the page. When I click on the button inside of the first instance that was created, 'remove me' is displayed in console as it should. Unfortunately, when I click on the delete button in any of the other instances of 'myTemp' I do not get 'remove me' in console. I don't understand why this is happening. How is it possible to remove each instance by clicking on it's delete button?

Thanks,
Nathan

myTemp.html

```
<template name="myTemp">
    <button type='button' class="btn remove">Delete</button>
</template>
```

myTemp.js

```
Template.myTemp.events({
    'click .remove': function(e){

        console.log('Remove me!');
    }
});
```

Comment: you only have one button in that template?

Comment: set up jsfiddle, if you can.

Comment: Mr D, correct, there is only one button in the template. The button is actually suppose to remove the instance. I'll add that to the original post if that helps.

@user10, I have a jsFiddle, what are you referring to?

Comment: I've rephrased the question a bit and fixed the code. I hope that helps.

Comment: I copied you code in my project and everything works fine. When I click the first button I get the 'Remove me !' in the console and then when I click buttons from other template I get 'Remove me !' counter incremented in the console.

Comment: @ltbesh Thank you so much. I could not find what was wrong, but you confirmed that nothing was really wrong. My issue was that in my actual code I was using `id` instead of `class`.

Although, I don't understand why it doesn't work with `id`. Either way, it works now. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

With class your code is fine but if you use id it will not be as ids are supposed to be unique on the page.